# Animation like Android ICS All Apps drawer

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, viewflipper, android-viewpager

It is very hard to explain the effect I am looking for and the limitations of available viewGroups in SDK 15.

I would like to implement Android All App drawer style animation in my App when switching between views. 
- Current view can be scrolled out. It fades out with alpha animation going to 0.
- Child view comes from back and has Scale and Alpha Animation.
- Views can be scrolled or can do Swipe Fling

Best possible ViewGroup in SDK is viewPager from compatibility package. 
It allows the finger scroll effect but can only assign 1 Animation to the viewPager.

I have tired using the View Flipper which allows In and Out animation but it does not allow view scrolling like viewPager. Also there can only be 1 view can be displayed at a time.

Is there any other viewGroup which allows following
- In and Out Animation
- Finger Scroll 
- More than one view on Surface at a time.

Below is the video of Android All Apps drawer (Watch after 0:19 seconds)
Video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XjRE_R9UDY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that there is a new View Group in android called StackView available from 3.0 Release which allows view to be stacked on top of each other and also can let us implement In and Out animation